# Is there anyway to be able to take a users input and place that in the file path

Tags: python-3.x

As you can see in the image I am going through the path file but i was hoping to be able to take the input of the user as 'track' and place that into the file path to search for a specific photo such as where it says /'Monza' in the file path. [F1 Application code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiaHj.png)

I have tried to use CV2 but due to system requirement I cannot use it. any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: elcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5781499)